# The viewport meta tag on Chrome for android disables some functionality of my web application

Tags: android, html, reactjs, google-chrome, dom

I'm facing a problem with the viewport meta tag. We've build an application in reactJS which uses [react-id-swiper](https://github.com/kidjp85/react-id-swiper) to display clickable elements that triggers a pop-up. To display the mobile version correctly i need this meta tag viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
```

The elements within the swiper are working fine on desktop and iOS but in the chrome application for Android the elements are visible but not clickable nor touchable (no problem in firefox for android though). We've pin pointed the problem and concluded that if we leave the content="" empty it does work but the scaling isn't correct anymore. We've also tried other options inside the content="" but we've concluded that we need initial-scale=1.0 for the correct scaling but this option also destroys the functionality.

So I think the problem is that chrome is setting some default viewport meta tag that somehow disables the swiper onClick.

The question:

Is it possible to manipulate the way Chrome for Android is handling this meta tag and set it the same as, for example, Firefox on Android is handling it?